# Input file button on IE 8 is highlighting "Browse..." text

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an asp.net, mvc 3 app which shows a page with the following in it:

```
<input type="file" id="binary" name="binary"/>
```

On IE the "Browse..." text is getting highlighted, making the button look like rubbish:

[image: Button with highlighted Browse text]

When you don't highlight it, it looks like this

[image: Browse button looks correct]

This only happens after a load or refresh of the page, and only if the Browse button is the first button I move the mouse over.  I expanded the size of the button, and you can see the white highlight of the button.

[image: The browse button expanded]

This is very odd and only happens on ie.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any CSS set for the input?

Comment: I created a version with no CSS to see if it was that, and I still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shots I found that there might be `background:white` css you have applied.
If it is please remove it by,

```
input[type="file"]{
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: As soon as I put a background or background-color entry in, I lose the XP round buttons and the button changes to a square one.  It no longer highlights on roll-over, so the problem goes away, but it is a little too dramatic. :-)